# Is it considered good practice to run celery workers in production using docker containers?

Tags: python, docker, celery, devops

In the celery documentation it is recommended to daemonize worker in production machine. Starting the worker with:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

is only for development and using nohup is not good enough.
Is executing this in docker containers good enough? Is daemonizing celery worker with systemd/upstart necessary?

Comment: I feel like I've seen SO questions doing this; in general I don't see anything wrong with running job queue workers in containers, subject to the usual constraints (_e.g._, it must be a foreground process).  Is there a specific issue you're encountering?

Comment: It is a new infrastructure I will set up. If someone has experience going down a similar path and encountered problems  then I would like to avoid it.